# Timezone methods not changing the current Instant time

Tags: java

I want to return the current time (Instant) in a certain `TimeZone` : I tried with the following chunks of code :

```
Instant now2 =  Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now2,
ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore")); 
System.out.println("Singapore"+ zdt.toInstant());
```

with this :

```
Instant nowUtc = Instant.now();
ZoneId asiaSingapore = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
ZonedDateTime nowAsiaSingapore = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(nowUtc, asiaSingapore);
```

or also :

```
Instant timeStamp= Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime timestampAtGMTPlus1= timeStamp.atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT+02:00"));
Instant nowGMT = timestampAtGMTPlus1.toInstant();
System.out.println("In 'GMT+01:00' Time Zone:"+ nowGMT);
```

But neither seems to be producing any different time from the current one (`Instant.now()`)
Is there a prior config to set for the timezone to be modified ?
What's wrong with my Instant Class (Java 8) ?

UPDATE : in all three the result is `2020-08-04T16:08:59.062Z`

For Mathew : your solution is outputting : `23:08:59.063594500` which is a no-information to me.

Comment: An instant has no time zone. Print the ZDT, not the Instant.

Comment: I want the final time format to be an Instant one

Comment: Whatever you precisely mean by Instant, it's not what `java.time.Instant` represents. `java.time.Instant` has no time zone.

Comment: I want the ouput to be `2020-08-04T16:08:59.062Z` but in the timezone that i want.

Comment: If the output includes "Z", that can't be "in the tome zone you want" - because "Z" means "UTC". It would really help if you could give a full concrete example of what you want and why, at what point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this

```
ZoneId asiaSingapore = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
Instant inst = LocalDateTime.now(asiaSingapore).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);  
System.out.println(inst);
```

Comment: you meant `System.out.println(inst); `

Comment: That's the answer i wanted to have thanks for the great HELP !

Comment: Doing this makes **zero sense**. This is not what an `Instant` is meant to represent, an `Instant` is always at UTC. For example, if it is 2020-08-03T17:51:00 in Asia/Singapore right now, this will derive an instant that is 2020-08-03T17:51:00 **UTC**.

Answer (score 1):

Instant is **always** UTC. The class you are looking for is called `LocalTime`:

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore"));
System.out.println("The time in Singapore is: " + zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime());
zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
System.out.println("The time in London is: " + zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime());
```

Gives:

```
The time in Singapore is: 2020-08-04T23:21:00.238406800
The time in London is: 2020-08-04T16:21:00.238406800
```

Comment: You mean you want to format it as a date string? Check out: https://www.baeldung.com/java-format-zoned-datetime-string

Comment: I want : `zdt.toLocalTime()` to be formatted as an Instant

Comment: If you turn it back to an instant, then you *should* and *will* lose the time zone information. An Instant has no time zone.  So you'll just get Instant.now().

Comment: Yes that was my problem. But then how to format to Instant a localTime ?

Comment: Eventhough the second solution isn't converting back to Instant and still doesnt output the correct time

Comment: Suggest you update / repost the question with what you've tried, the output you are getting, and the output you were hoping to get.

Comment: Sorry Mathew but the outputted time is of no use for me. Therefore i cannot accept your answer as correct

Comment: Sure see Update please

Comment: Do you want `toLocalDateTime()` instead?

Comment: You can print the string however you like, see my link above! :)

Comment: It is comparable with an Instant ?